# split header of string

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I want to reformat the lines below. Please see input example and desired output. I have been messing around with awk without finding the correct solution

Input:

```
>1-672762
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTT
>2-240457
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTT
>3-130231
TAGCAGCACGTAAATATTGGCG
>4-116485
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT
```

Output (needs to be tab separated):

```
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTT  672762
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTT  240457
TAGCAGCACGTAAATATTGGCG  130231
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT  116485
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne '/^>\d+-(\d+)/ or print "$_\t$1"' file
```

Output:

```
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTT    672762
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTT    240457
TAGCAGCACGTAAATATTGGCG    130231
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT    116485
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach in perl ("-" is chr(055)):

```
perl -wln055e's/(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/$2\t$1/s and print'
```

or

```
perl -wlp055e'BEGIN{<>}s/(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/$2\t$1/s'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F- '/>/{x=$2;next} {print $0 "\t" x}' file
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTT  672762
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTT  240457
TAGCAGCACGTAAATATTGGCG  130231
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT  116485
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/^[^-]*-(.*)\n(.*)/\2\t\1/' file
```